# Can't eager load List in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, domain-driven-design, eager-loading

I'm trying to eager load all collections in one of the domain objects:
`Book > Chapter > Page > Cell`. Using a structure like:

```
.sln
- API (Startup.cs, Controllers)
- Core (Entities, Services)
- Infrastructure (DbContext)
```

I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'Book' does not contain a definition for 'Chapters' and no accessible extension method 'Chapters' accepting a first argument of type 'Book' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\pebes\Source\Repos\ip6_uiux-ereader-app\book_designer\API\API.csproj   C:\Users\pebes\Source\Repos\ip6_uiux-ereader-app\book_designer\API\Program.cs   36
```

Relevant Code Fragments:
`Program.cs`

```
using(var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{ 
   var scopedProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
   var context = scopedProvider.GetRequiredService<BookDesinerContext>();

    var books = context.Books
        .Include(book => book.Chapters)
        .ThenInclude(chapter => chapter.Pages)
        .ThenInclude(page => page.Cells)
        .ToList();
}
```

(Adapted from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

`Book.cs`

```
using Core.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core.Entities.BookAggregate
{
    public class Book : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
    {
        String Title { get; set; }

        List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }

        // EF needs empty private constructor
        private Book()
        { 
            Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
        }

        public Book(string title) 
        {
            Title = title;
            Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
        }

        public void AddChapter(Chapter chapter)
        { 
            Chapters.Add(chapter);
        }

        public void AddAllChapters(List<Chapter> chapters)
        {
            Chapters.AddRange(chapters);
        }
    }
}
```

`Chapter.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core.Entities
{
    public class Chapter : BaseEntity
    {
        String Title { get; set; }
        List<Page> Pages { get; set; }

        public Chapter(String title)
        {
            Title = title;
            Pages = new List<Page>();
        }

        public void AddPage(Page page)
        {
            Pages.Add(page);
        }

        public void AddAllPages(List<Page> pages)
        {
            Pages.AddRange(pages);
        }
    }

}
```

`DbContext`

```
using Core.Entities.BookAggregate;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class BookDesinerContext : DbContext
    {
        public BookDesinerContext(DbContextOptions<BookDesinerContext> options) : base(options)
        { 
        }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
    }
}
```

How and where do I fix this error?

Comment: `Chapters` is not public?

Comment: You haven't explicitly specified the connection between the two tables. Try adding public Book Book { get; set; } as well as public whateveryourtypeis BookId { get; set; }. Doing this will allow ef to make the connection. Either that, or specify it in Fluent Api in your context or configuration

Comment: Since Chapters isn't public, use `.Include("Chapters")`.